# jsonify takes too much time in my flask application

Tags: python, json, rest, flask

I have a flask-restful api, and for a simple request it can takes 5 to 30 seconds to respond.

using a profiler, i saw that a huge amount of time was used in jsonify calls :

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000   24.112   24.112  my_api.py:72(decorated_function)
    1    0.000    0.000   24.109   24.109  checkSystem.py:11(decorated_function)
    1    0.019    0.019   24.109   24.109  __init__.py:521(decorated_function)
    1    0.007    0.007   24.066   24.066  my_api.py:135(get)
    1    0.000    0.000   20.960   20.960  json.py:201(jsonify)
    1    0.000    0.000   20.960   20.960  json.py:114(dumps)
    1    0.024    0.024   20.960   20.960  __init__.py:274(dumps)
    1    1.215    1.215   20.936   20.936  encoder.py:248(encode)
2142307/2043811    2.736    0.000   19.689    0.000 encoder.py:600(_iterencode)
7781216/2043811   10.640    0.000   17.306    0.000 encoder.py:513(_iterencode_dict)
2166915/2043795    2.840    0.000   12.561    0.000 encoder.py:424(_iterencode_list)
    1    0.109    0.109    3.099    3.099  historyDao.py:4(getHistory)
2142370    1.516    0.000    1.516  0.000  {isinstance}
.......
```

you can see that i also spend 3 seconds in my DAO, that's because my dataset is not so small.

I can see that there is many calls to the encoder script, but i only call jsonify once, so i don't really know how to reduce that.
Do you know how jsonify can be so long ?

In case it could help, here is an example of response :

```
{
"stationHistory": {
"features": [
  {
    "geometry": {
      "coordinates": [
        45.75118,
        4.884795
      ],
      "type": "Point"
    },
    "id": "3079",
    "properties": {
      "RGB": "rgb(0,96,160)",
      "address": "address",
      "banking": 1,
      "bikes": 3,
      "extra": "\"extra\"",
      "free_slots": 13,
      "last_update": "1420625383000",
      "movable": 0,
      "name": "3079 - PLACE LOUISE",
      "status": 1,
      "tms_gmt": "Wed, 07 Jan 2015 10:15:03 GMT",
      "total_slots": 0
    },
    "type": "Feature"
    }
],
"type": "FeatureCollection"
}
}
```

with, of course, many more features. I have not a "recursive" json, with a lot of dictionaries into other dictionaries. so i can't explain the number of calls.

I'll try to show some code.

i have a simple flask restful app, nothing particular, here is an example class :

```
class Historic(restful.Resource):
    @somewrappers
    @cache.memoize(60)
    def get(self, some_args):
        parser = MyParser()
        parser.add_argument('arg1', type=int, help="Can't read arg1")
        args = parser.parse_args()
        historic = historyDao.getHistory(
            currentConnection,
            some_args,
            args.get('arg1', None),
        )
        return jsonify(historic)
```

and my dao execute an sql request, no problem with it, and stores the result in a geojson format :

```
featureList = []
for station in data:
    station['RGB'] = utils.getRGB(station, system)
    featureList.append(utils.createFeature(station))
featureCollection = utils.createFeatureCollection(featureList)
response_dict = {'stationHistory' : featureCollection}
return response_dict
```

functions from utils module are just adding the extra geojson stuff, "features:", "properties:", you can see the result in the json example

Comment: "In case it could help": what always helps is source code.

Comment: How many is "many more features"?

Comment: I can't add source code I will try to make a short example

Comment: when i do the same request with less features (with the same database, filtering results) i have a reponse in few milliseconds. When i don't filter, i end up with hundreds of thousands of features

Comment: In that case the amount of data is obviously the problem. You should deliver it in chunks. `flask.ext.sqlalchemy.Pagination` could be helpful for that.

Comment: Ok. I was comparing to an old and ugly version of my api which was taking much less time for the same amount of data. But what I didn't think about, was that the response was much shorter for each data, so the weight of the answer was very reduced. 

I'll give a try to the pagination, and come back with some results. thank you.